# Disable button if a sum of number inputs is of certain value (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Given this HTML code:

```
<body onload="assessSum()">
        
        <input type="number" id="num0" min="0" max="10">
        <input type="number" id="num1" min="0" max="10">
        <button type="submit" id="sub">Submit</button>

</body>
```

What would be a function that would disable the submit button, if the sum of the 2 input fields is greater than a certain value?

My JavaScript/Jquery code doesn't seem to work:

```
function assessSum(){
    var total = 0;
    var maximum = 5;
    var bt = document.getElementById('sub');
    $.each($("input"),function(){
        total += parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
      });
      if(total > maximum){
          bt.disabled = true;
      }
      else{
          bt.disabled = false;
      }

}
```

Comment: So where are your event listeners? You need to check it onchange of the inputs

Comment: @epascarello I was able to make use of event listeners for a value of one input. When I added more, the problem occured. After a bit of googling, I opted for Jquery. Needless to say, that itself didn't solve the problem. So I posted my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the function on `change` event of the inputs.

```js
$(':input').on('change', assessSum);

function assessSum() {
  var total = 0;
  var maximum = 5;
  var bt = document.getElementById('sub');
  $("input").each((i, el) => {
    total += (parseInt(el.value) || 0);
  });
  
  if (total > maximum) {
    bt.disabled = true;
  } else {
    bt.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="num0" min="0" max="10">
<input type="number" id="num1" min="0" max="10">
<button type="submit" id="sub">Submit</button>
```

The disabling can also be done like this:

```
$('#sub').attr('disabled',  (total > maximum));
```